# How to make irregular time series data into regular time series data?

Tags: python, algorithm, time-series, dataset

I am doing analysis using time series data.

But there is a problem.

I have a problem with incorrect time intervals and would like to fix it.

For example, here are two datasets:

```
    **time stamp**          **value**        **time stamp**          **value**
    2020-01-01-01:00:00.00  1                2020-01-01-01:00:00.00  1
    2020-01-01-01:00:00.30  1                2020-01-01-01:00:00.30  1
    2020-01-01-01:00:00.60  1                2020-01-01-01:00:00.60  0
    2020-01-01-01:00:00.90  1                2020-01-01-01:00:00.90  0
    2020-01-01-01:00:01.20  1                2020-01-01-01:00:01.20  0
    2020-01-01-01:00:01.50  1                2020-01-01-01:00:01.50  0
    2020-01-01-01:00:01.80  0                2020-01-01-01:00:01.80  0
    2020-01-01-01:00:02.10  0                2020-01-01-01:00:02.10  0
    2020-01-01-01:00:02.40  0                2020-01-01-01:00:02.40  0
    2020-01-01-01:00:02.70  0                2020-01-01-01:00:02.70  0
```

I want to resampling the spacing of these two data.

Is there a way?

For example, the following data set is changed.

```
    **time stamp**          **value**        **time stamp**          **value**
    2020-01-01-01:00:00.00  1                2020-01-01-01:00:00.00  1
    2020-01-01-01:00:00.40  1                2020-01-01-01:00:00.40  1
    2020-01-01-01:00:00.80  1                2020-01-01-01:00:00.80  1
    2020-01-01-01:00:01.20  1                2020-01-01-01:00:01.20  1
    2020-01-01-01:00:01.60  1                2020-01-01-01:00:01.60  1
    2020-01-01-01:00:02.00  0                2020-01-01-01:00:02.00  0
    2020-01-01-01:00:02.40  0                2020-01-01-01:00:02.40  0
    2020-01-01-01:00:02.80  0                2020-01-01-01:00:02.80  0
    2020-01-01-01:00:03.20  0                2020-01-01-01:00:03.20  0
    2020-01-01-01:00:03.60  0                2020-01-01-01:00:03.60  0
```

Comment: Yes this is possible if you define the how to resample the value. Where are you stuck? BTW, I think that the resampled values of your second example is wrong (the  timesteps 2-4 should have value 0, right?).

Comment: @SaiBot  no. My intention is to match the time intervals of the two data sets equally.

Comment: Ok, then it is really unclear to me what you want to achieve. Can you give some background where the two time series come from, how they are related and why they need to be identical afterwards?

Comment: @SaiBot I am sorry for being late. hm...The two time series are sensor data. The two time series above are the same sensor. And I want to fit time series data for anomaly detection. But I found it hard to match the time series. So I'm looking for a new anomaly detection method.

Comment: How can they be from the same sensor, recording different values at identical timesteps? I see time_series_A, time_series_B and below resampled_time_series_A, resampled_time_series_B. How is this related to anomaly detection?

Comment: @SaiBot Sorry. I'm not good at English. So I did not understand your words.
My plan was to model abnormal time series data (upper, lower) to detect anomalies. But is there a better way to detect it in time series data?

Comment: So do you want to detect anomalies or do you want to resample your data?